# how to add noticafion after i click on an action after clicking on a button in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add a notification after the users submit a form
here's my controller;

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $data = request()->validate([
            'package' => 'required',
            'amt_paid' => 'required',
            'bankname' => 'required',   
        ]);

        auth()->user()->funds()->create($data);

        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        return redirect('funds.create')->with('status', 'successfully inserted');
    }
```

Comment: Hey Toby, what type of notification? A [window alert](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp)? You're already returning [flashed session data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) to the view.

Comment: yes but its showing my page not found error and not storing my data

Answer (score 0):

You can show your flash message in your view like this:

```
@if(session()->has('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session()->get('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Since you are already returning the status with a message from your controller

`return redirect('funds.create')->with('status', 'successfully inserted');`

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the session variable this way

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'package' => 'required',
        'amt_paid' => 'required',
        'bankname' => 'required',   
    ]);

    auth()->user()->funds()->create($data);

    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

    // Persistent session
    // session(['status'=>'successfully inserted']);

    return redirect('funds.create')->with(['status'=>'successfully inserted']);
}
```

and get the session variable in Laravel Blade this way

```
@if(session('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ session('status') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: i did this but i just get redirect to the create.blade.php but no status message

Comment: @TobyNwude, is `funds.create` inside your redirect a view or a route name?

Comment: @TobyNwude, See my edit. I previously used persistent session data. The corrected code flashes the session data to the current view.

Comment: its a view @udo E.

Comment: If the edited answer doesn't solve your problem, then check if any other blade @directive is preventing the notification display.  You can update your question by including the blade file code where you show the notification

Comment: thanks the error was from my model. the notification display is working